# When is a Handler associated to a looper?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, android-looper

It seems like just calling new Handler() associates the handler with the current thread’s looper without any thread-specific arguments being passed to the constructor.

1. How does it identify what the current thread is, though?
2. Why is calling new Handler() in specific methods (onLooperPrepared(), onCreate() ) mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

> How does it identify what the current thread is, though?

If you dive into the calling `new Handler()`, you'll see the source code, I'll show you :

[image]

The red rectangle shows you that you need a `Looper` when you `new Handler`.

The case `mLooper==null` only occurs when you call `new Handler` not in the UI thread, or you didn't call `Looper.prepare()` in your work-thread.

Also, you can associate the handler with the current thread’s looper obviously, refer to [Define a handler on the UI thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui#Handler), like `handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`.

Answer (score 0):

> How does it identify what the current thread is, though?

By calling `Thread.currentThread()`static method

> Why is calling new Handler() in specific methods (onLooperPrepared(), onCreate() ) mandatory?

It actually is not mandatory depending on the task you want your handler to do.
But in general Looper is required for Handler to process messages.

More: [How to Use Thread, Looper and Handler in Android](https://link.medium.com/hzDAkPyj4Z)

Comment: the link is 404

Comment: @Robbit not sure why, probably it is a dynamic link. I have fixed it, but it probably will become invalid again. Will check tomorrow